# Adding content at cusor location, Outlook VSTO AddIn

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

I am creating my first Addin for Outlook 2010, it's for using emojis that are added to the email body when a button on the custom ribbon is pressed.

I currently have it so that when a button is pressed the corresponding emoji is added to the end of the email.
My main issue is that I don't want to just add the emoji at the end of the HTMLBody but at the current location of the cursor, is there any way to do this with Outlook 2010?

I tried using this [tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6b9478cs(v=vs.100).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-11).
However any use of Application.Selection gives me an error cs1061: "Application does not contain a definition for Selection...", I'm assuming that this is because I'm using Outlook 2010 and not Outlook 2013 or later but correct me if I'm wrong.

All and any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Application.Selection` refers to the Word Object Model, but you are using Outlook's Application. What you need is `Application.ActiveInspector.WordEditor.Application.Selection` (where `Application.ActiveInspector.WordEditor` in OOM returns the Document Word Object Model  object corresponding to the editor window of the active Outlook inspector).